# Laravel: Is there a way to remove DB query clauses?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let us say my shop model has a products relationship as follows:

```
// shop model class

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Model\Product::class)
        ->orderBy('name');
}
```

Is there a way that client code, such as my controller, can remove the `orderBy()` clause?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that, say in your controller you want to fetch some of the products

```
\App\Products::latest()->getQuery();
```

`getQuery()` is a query builder method that contains all the groupings, selects, orders, wheres, joins etc for the query that you are accessing or trying to build.

So you could reset the ordering like so:

```
\App\Products::latest()->getQuery()->orders= [];
```

since in Laravel eloquent query builder selects, grouping, ordering are stored as arrays of key values you simply set that to an empty array to reset al the previous states.

For example grouping:

```
\App\Products::latest()->getQuery()->groupings =[];
```

Comment: This also works for the `limit` clause of course. But just don't make the same mistake as me and remember to also remove the `offset` clause if you have one.

`$query->limit = null;
$query->offset = null;`

This is extremely useful if you are using [Datatables](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/) for Laravel and you need to use the same parameters as the original table query, but without a `limit` (pagination) clause.

Comment: I checked it in Laravel 5.8+ groupings are named as "groups".

Comment: In Laravel 7+ (at least through 10) there is a reorder() method to clear existing order by clauses.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#removing-existing-orderings

Answer (score 2):

For reset

```
$qry->getQuery()->groups = [];
$qry->getQuery()->wheres = [];
```

For remove last where or group by column

```
array_pop($qry->getQuery()->groups);

array_pop($qry->getQuery()->wheres);
```

Comment: just doing so might mess up the bindings and you'd probably want to filter them too...

Answer (score 0):

```
public function products($isOrder = true)
{
    $hasMany = $this->hasMany(Model\Product::class);
    return ($idOrder) ? $hasMany->orderBy('name') : $hasMany;
}
```

but you can use this only having  $shop instance;

```
$shop->products(false)->...; // your query to get result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [cloneForPaginationCount](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getCountForPagination) function of the Database Query Builder.

If you have the model instance you can go to this function by doing:

```
$eloquent->getQuery()->getCountForPagination();
```

If you see the flow, it reaches the protected function `cloneForPaginationCount` which clones the query but without the `['orders', 'limit', 'offset']`.

So simple and so useful.